# Well displaying the Y-axis on jFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Please how can I change the Y-axis to have data displayed with the same number of digits.

[This is what I have on my graph](http://www.123.ro/capture.jpg)

and this is the code that produces that part of the graph

```
final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot)result.getPlot ();
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.BLACK);
plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setRange (1.2, 1.3);
rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createStandardTickUnits ());
rangeAxis.setTickUnit (new NumberTickUnit(0.005));
```

As you can see, I fix the begin at 1.2 and the end at 1.3 and I define the TickUnit at 0.005. So normaly (I think) I should have something gradualy like :
1.2 1.205 1.210 ... 1.305

[This is what I would like to obtain](http://www.123.ro/capture2.jpg)

How can I modify the code to obtain the Y-axis with gradues values ?
Thanks

I think I have found this solution

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setRange (1.200, 1.300);
rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createStandardTickUnits ());
rangeAxis.setTickUnit (new NumberTickUnit(0.005, df, 0));
```

it seems to work fine.
Thanks

Comment: What is the result of you code and how does it differ from your desired outcome?

Comment: I have edit the code with the links to screen capture to what i have and what i need to have at the end.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chart axis will accept a `java.text.NumberFormat` instance, which it will use to format the labels. To do this, try adding these lines to your code:

```
DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(newFormat);
```